# | discord.py | "NameError: name 'message' is not defined"

Tags: python, discord, bots

File "C:\Users\nil27\Desktop\discord12\botdiscord.py", line 40, in gen_element
var = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name = '784837948134785055')
NameError: name 'message' is not defined

When I want to add a role, can you help me please.

```
@bot.command()
async def gen_element(ctx):
    choice = random.choice(['Feu', 'Eau', 'Terre', 'Vent', 'Foudre'])
    member = ctx.message.author
    var = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name = '784837948134785055')
    if choice == 'Feu':
        await ctx.send("Vous avez débloqué l'élément feu  !")
        member.add_role(var)
```

Comment: Since you don't have `message` defined anywhere in the function, this throws an error.

Comment: Did you mean to use `ctx.message` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess based on the function you gave that you forgot to the add the parent object ctx to the .get

This should work

```
@bot.command()
async def gen_element(ctx):
    choice = random.choice(['Feu', 'Eau', 'Terre', 'Vent', 'Foudre'])
    member = ctx.message.author
    var = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = '784837948134785055')
    if choice == 'Feu':
        await ctx.send("Vous avez débloqué l'élément feu  !")
        await discord.Member.add_roles(member, var)
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\nil27\Desktop\discord12\botdiscord.py", line 43, in gen_element
    member.add_role(var)
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'add_role'

Comment: @NilouLeLoup Try add_roles(member, var) instead of add_role. I have also changed my answer

Comment: C:\Users\nil27\Desktop\discord12\botdiscord.py:43: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Member.add_roles' was never awaited
  discord.Member.add_roles(member, var)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback                      @Crapy

Comment: Try add await to it @NilouLeLoup